# Mostrar campos relacionados en ListView

Tags: django

tengo este problema pero no encuentro como resolverlo.

es lo siguiente tengo dos modelos uno llamado Marca y otro llamado Monitor.
En la tabla Monitor hago una llamada al campo nombre del modelo marca, todos sin problema me guarda bien el formulario en el formulario me muestra bien el campo nombre, pero cuando guardo me guarda en el Modelo Monitor el id del nombre que escogi, y al hacer un listado con ListView me sale el id y no el nombre, como puedo resolver este problema???

slds

aca les dejo el codigo

**Vista Monitor**

```
 class MonitorList(ListView):
    model = Monitor 
    paginate_by = 10;

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Monitor.objects.prefetch_related('marca')
```

** Modelo Monitor **

```
class Monitor(models.Model):
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Marca del Monitor');
    serial = models.CharField('# Serial', max_length=100, unique=True);
    modelo = models.CharField('Modelo del Monitor', max_length=100);

    def __str__(self):
        return self.serial
```

** Vista Marca **

```
class MarcaList(ListView):
    model = Marca; 
    paginate_by = 10;

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title']='Listado de Marcas'
        return context
```

** Modelo Marca **

```
class Marca(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField('Nombre de Marca', max_length=100, unique=True);

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya resolvi mi pregunta expuesta, lo realice de forma sencilla estaba imprimiendo en mi plantilla de forma erroena la cosulta realizada mediante ListView, aca les dejo el codigo de como lo resolvi.

**View**

```
class MarcaList(ListView):
    model = Marca; 
    paginate_by = 10;

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title']='Listado de Marcas'
        return context
```

**Template**

```
 {% for monitor in object_list %}
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{monitor.marca}}</td>
                                            <td>{{monitor.serial}}</td>
                                            <td>{{monitor.modelo}}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <ul>
                                                    
                                                </ul>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        {% endfor %}
```

En mi caso estaba agregando en donde dice `{{monitor.marca}}`, `{{monitor.marca_id}}` y esto probocaba que me mostrara el id por el cual fue registrado en el modelo marca de la aplicación.

espero esto pueda ayudar.

slds